# Can not find DoubleClick in XAML

Tags: xaml, double-click

I have a ListView control in XAML.
The items are defined by a template control with a TextBlock inside a Grid.
Now I want to trigger an action when I double click the TextBlock.
To my surprise I find there is no DoubleClick event to hook up ... !
I thought it was just the TextBlock that din't have it, but actually no controls have it.
I look for DoubleClick and MouseDoubleClick but they are definitely absent.

I have read suggestions where an EventTrigger is added to a control with Gesture="MouseDoubleClick". It looks promising but in my case the compiler complains and tells me there is no such gesture as a MouseDoubleClick. Same with DoubleClick.

Did the DoubleClick disappear in some version of .Net?
I have .Net Framework 4.5 and the project is WPF Application.

Do I have to do stupid workarounds by detecting MouseDown and check the elapsed time since last MouseDown? Sounds like stoneage ...

Comment: Silverlight 5 only supports double click events.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is always refreshing to formulate your problem!
After thinking a while I thought maybe they added a counter to the mouse events instead of having separate events.
That seems to be the case!!!
The MouseButtonEventArgs has a ClickCount property. When checking for value 2 I detect my DoubleClick!

Still a bit odd though to just kick out the DoubleClick. Even after searching I find no reference as to when and why it disappeared.

Comment: Really Awesome Answer 
thanks for your time and efforts

Answer (score 26):

Just to show the solution Jakob means:

```
private void img_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.ClickCount == 2)
            {
                //DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
```

Comment: Funny thing is that this works only with the MouseDown event. In the MouseUp event, e.ClickCount is 1 even after a double click.

Answer (score 10):

Use content ContentControl, Luke!

```
<ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="OnDoubleClick"> 
    <TextBlock Text="Hello" FontSize="15" /> 
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: I found this solution to work more consistently. Originally I did the click count monitoring as most seemed to agree to that solution and it did work. I have made updates to the controls and something broke it however. It seems I am just getting multiple click events of "One Click" which does not allow me to differentiate single click from double click (unless I put a timer in). Wrapping the textblock in a content control exposed the double click on that content control and that event seems to fire as expected.